# Left outer join not being honoured

Tags: c#, entity-framework

We have the following EF code:

```
    var qry =
            from c in db.Contacts

            join comp in db.Companies on c.CompanyId equals comp.CompanyId
                into compLeft
            from cj in compLeft.DefaultIfEmpty()

            select new CompleteUserDlModel
            {
                CompanyName = cj.Company1,
                CompanyId = c.CompanyId
            };
```

which generates this SQL

```
SELECT 
    [Extent1].[CompanyId] AS [CompanyId], 
    [Extent2].[Company] AS [Company]
    FROM  [dbo].[Contacts] AS [Extent1]
    INNER JOIN [dbo].[Company] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[CompanyId] = [Extent2].[CompanyId]
```

but we actually want

```
SELECT 
    [Extent1].[CompanyId] AS [CompanyId], 
    [Extent2].[Company] AS [Company]
    FROM  [dbo].[Contacts] AS [Extent1]
    LEFT OUTER JOIN [dbo].[Company] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[CompanyId] = [Extent2].[CompanyId]
```

Could someone point out what we've done wrong, please?

All the refs on left outer joins in C# EF (i.e. [LEFT OUTER JOIN in LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3404975/left-outer-join-in-linq)) point to the syntax we're using. Clearly, we're missing something.

Comment: What version of EF are you using? Are those two tables are related in your schema and relationship is represented in your model?

Comment: I think you need to explicitly provide the null value case in the select statement e.g. if CompanyName is a string:   CompanyName = cj.Company1??"  ".

Comment: Thanks for the responses. We're using EF 6.2.0. Company.CompanyId is the PK. Contacts.CompanyId is an FK on Company.CompanyId. I had a look in the edmx file and the relationship seems to be there.

Comment: David Browne's answer below got to the root of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Could someone point out what we've done wrong, please?

Probably you have `Contact.CompanyId` a typed as `int` instead of `int?`, making it a required property, and so EF assumes you have referential integrity when generating a query.

But, as always, `left join` in LINQ has bad code smell, and can almost always be replaced by just querying your target entity and traversing its Navigation Properties.  EG:

```
 from c in db.Contacts
 select new
 {
     CompanyName = c.CompanyId.HasValue?c.Company.CompanyName : null,
     CompanyId = c.CompanyId
 };
```

Comment: Quite right - CompanyId was not nullable.
Not sure the code smells though - smells OK on my machine ;-)
Thanks for the response; I learnt something from that.

Answer (score 0):

```
var qry =
            from c in db.Contacts

            join comp in db.Companies on c.CompanyId equals comp.CompanyId
                into compLeft
            from cj in compLeft.DefaultIfEmpty()

            select new CompleteUserDlModel
            {
                CompanyName = cj.Company1,
                CompanyId = c?.CompanyId ?? String.Empty
            };
```

Comment: `?.` is not allowed in expression trees.